# Should eating before bedtime be avoided if someone wants to lose weight?

Tags: diet, sleep, weight-loss, time-of-day, body-weight

I have read many contradictory articles regarding eating before bedtime for someone trying to lose weight. Here some examples:

http://www.nytimes.com/2011/05/17/health/17really.html?_r=4&adxnnl=1&adxnnlx=1335121216-Q4q6iChMxGm7qr5Lq3+Jsg

http://time.com/3020266/you-asked-will-eating-before-bed-make-me-fat/

**Are there any proven evidence in the literature that eating before bedtime favors or prevents weight loss?**

Comment: Small amounts of protein and carbohydrate aid in metabolize fat but I don't have a any reverence to cite.

Answer (score 3):

There is some experimental evidence that suggests that those who front load ( have their main meals earlier in the day ) are more likely to lose weight than those who eat later.

**BACKGROUND**:
There is emerging literature demonstrating a relationship between the timing of feeding and weight regulation in animals. However, whether the timing of food intake influences the success of a weight-loss diet in humans is unknown.

**OBJECTIVE**:
To evaluate the role of food timing in weight-loss effectiveness in a sample of 420 individuals who followed a 20-week weight-loss treatment.

**METHODS**:
Participants (49.5% female subjects; age (mean ± s.d.): 42 ± 11 years; BMI: 31.4 ± 5.4 kg m(-2)) were grouped in early eaters and late eaters, according to the timing of the main meal (lunch in this Mediterranean population). 51% of the subjects were early eaters and 49% were late eaters (lunch time before and after 1500 hours, respectively), energy intake and expenditure, appetite hormones, CLOCK genotype, sleep duration and chronotype were studied.

**RESULTS**:
Late lunch eaters lost less weight and displayed a slower weight-loss rate during the 20 weeks of treatment than early eaters (P=0.002). Surprisingly, energy intake, dietary composition, estimated energy expenditure, appetite hormones and sleep duration was similar between both groups. Nevertheless, late eaters were more evening types, had less energetic breakfasts and skipped breakfast more frequently that early eaters (all; P<0.05). CLOCK rs4580704 single nucleotide polymorphism (SNP) associated with the timing of the main meal (P=0.015) with a higher frequency of minor allele (C) carriers among the late eaters (P=0.041). Neither sleep duration, nor CLOCK SNPs or morning/evening chronotype was independently associated with weight loss (all; P>0.05).

**CONCLUSIONS:**
Eating late may influence the success of weight-loss therapy. Novel therapeutic strategies should incorporate not only the caloric intake and macronutrient distribution - as is classically done - but also the timing of food.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23357955

Another paper suggests that there are metabolic sequelae if you have your main calories late in the day

**Abstract**
**Objective**
Few studies examined the association between time-of-day of nutrient intake and the metabolic syndrome. Our goal was to compare a weight loss diet with high caloric intake during breakfast to an isocaloric diet with high caloric intake at dinner.

**Design and Methods**
Overweight and obese women (BMI 32.4 ± 1.8 kg/m2) with metabolic syndrome were randomized into two isocaloric (∼1400 kcal) weight loss groups, a breakfast (BF) (700 kcal breakfast, 500 kcal lunch, 200 kcal dinner) or a dinner (D) group (200 kcal breakfast, 500 kcal lunch, 700 kcal dinner) for 12 weeks.

**Results**
The BF group showed greater weight loss and waist circumference reduction. Although fasting glucose, insulin, and ghrelin were reduced in both groups, fasting glucose, insulin, and HOMA-IR decreased significantly to a greater extent in the BF group. Mean triglyceride levels decreased by 33.6% in the BF group, but increased by 14.6% in the D group. Oral glucose tolerance test led to a greater decrease of glucose and insulin in the BF group. In response to meal challenges, the overall daily glucose, insulin, ghrelin, and mean hunger scores were significantly lower, whereas mean satiety scores were significantly higher in the BF group.

**Conclusions**
High-calorie breakfast with reduced intake at dinner is beneficial and might be a useful alternative for the management of obesity and metabolic syndrome.

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/oby.20460/abstract